# powershell get-clipboard then match against list in excel

Tags: powershell

**What i am trying to do:**

Bring up the description of a BOM# that is in either PDF, Excel or DWG from a copied piece of text of the BOM#. I have a master list of the BOM#'s and the corresponding description along with their legacy BOM#. I was thinking I could assign a hotkey to run the PowerShell script. Then Copy the BOM# then press the hotkey combo and have a popup of the BOM# that i copied with its description and the old legacy BOM# all next to each other.

Currently in my PDFs the text is a locked AutoCAD SHX font, but when i click on it and hit Ctrl-C then check it with PowerShell with `Get-Clipboard` the copied text appears correctly. How can i use that `Get-Clipboard` to check my spreadsheet with an `index-match` function to popup a box of the description and the legacy BOM#?

Is PowerShell even the right starting point for this? My Co-worker is trying AHK and is getting close but keeping it in some software that all other co-workers computers have would be much smoother.

Thanks for any help

Comment: What is `BOM#` in this context? Bill of Matertials? Byte-order mark?

Comment: Bill of Materials, sorry my industry standard. Never head of Byte-order-Mark before.

Comment: @MattTaylor Just to clarify, are you saying that you want the script to copy the BOM# from the pdf? Or that is being done manually, correct? Then after it is copied to clipboard, the script runs with a hotkey to provide the matched data?